# Can you dynamically instantiate a Custom MetaData object in the same dynamic way you can an SObject?

Tags: custom-metadata, dynamic-apex

With SObjects we can do something like:

```
sObject sob = [Select id,name from Account limit 1][0];
```

Can you do the equivilent with Custom Metadata? For example does something like this exist:

```
customMetaData CMD = [Select MasterLabel from mycustommetadata__mdt limit 1][0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

You have to use SObject as follows:

```
SObject so = [SELECT masterlabel FROM Queue_Level_Milestone_SLA__mdt limit 1][0];
```

In my org, it returns as follows in debug log where `Implementation` is the first record of this Custom Metadata Type:

> 00:47:42:006 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [1]|so|{"MasterLabel":"Implementation","Id":"m011Q000000bnl8QAA"}|0x68c866f5